# Почему пайчарм не видит содержимое библиотеки

Tags: python, pycharm, lib, файловые-пути

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему в пайчарме невозможно импортировать модули из библиотеки ЕСЛИ Я ВИЖУ ЧТО ОНИ СУЩЕСТВУЮТ ПО ВЫБРАННОМУ ПУТИ

Comment: Не добавляйте данные в виде скриншотов.

Comment: Импортируйте не `email.mine.multipart`, а `.multipart`.